# Subtitle block in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I am having a small problem with `mdframed.sty`. The subtitle block seems to have a `0.4pt` frame with the same color of the subtitle background. This causes the left and right ends of the subtitle frame to intrude a bit into the overall linewidth of the frame:

[image: mdframed subtitle frame problem]

This is directly from the code in the users guide:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newmdenv[%
    roundcorner=5pt,
    subtitlebelowline=true,subtitleaboveline=true,
    subtitlebackgroundcolor=yellow!70!white,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20!white,
    frametitle={Theorem},frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow!70!white,
]{subtitleenv}


\begin{document}

\begin{subtitleenv}
Some Text \ldots
\mdfsubtitle{Notes}
Some Text \ldots
\end{subtitleenv}

\end{document}
```

I looked at the code (and very lucid it is) but can find no incantation that  addresses the `linewidth` of subtitle frame as a whole.

Suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm that this is clearly not an artifact produced by the PDF viewer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `mdfsubtitlebackground` style (found in the file `md-frame-1.mdf` which provides the style for `mdframed` with the option `framemethod=tikz`) uses `draws` using the background color; the definition:

```
\tikzset{mdfsubtitlebackground/.style={%
   draw=\mdf@subtitlebackgroundcolor,
   fill=\mdf@subtitlebackgroundcolor,
  }%
}
```

A simple fix is to set this style using `draw=none`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
mdfsubtitlebackground/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=\mdf@subtitlebackgroundcolor}
}
\makeatother

\newmdenv[%
    innerlinewidth=0.2pt,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    subtitlebelowline=true,subtitleaboveline=true,
    subtitlebackgroundcolor=yellow!70!white,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20!white,
    frametitle={Theorem},frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow!70!white,
]{subtitleenv}

\begin{document}

\begin{subtitleenv}
Some Text \ldots
\mdfsubtitle{Notes}
Some Text \ldots
\end{subtitleenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As the package author has commented, this issue has been now fixed and it will be corrected in a new version of the package.

Comment: I didn't missed the space. I missed the correct definition. Instead of `draw` I wanted to use `path`. However a small fix is: `\tikzset{mdfsubtitlebackground/.style={draw=none,fill=\mdf@subtitlebackgroundcolor}}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I also considered this, but I wasn't sure if the idea was to also have the possibility (at some point) to draw a frame for the subtitle. I have to leave now, but I'll edit my answer later... or, if you can, feel free to add your own answer, or edit mine ;-)

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/commit/48bd62109ff9c70bea8c8f17dbf34ec332e11571 ;-) -- The lines are drawn by an extra tikz style so I think that `path` is a good choice.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel great! I also updated my answer. Please let me know if you think it's OK now.